# Error trying to convert Media player code from JavaScript into ReactJS: Unexpected token

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to write my own custom media player but am having a number of issues.

I understand JavaScript, but I don't understand how the below JavaScript gets converted to ReactJS. Note: I have changed the media player id to `#player`

The error I get is

```
  Line 5:  Parsing error: Unexpected token  3 | export default class MediaPlayer extends Component{
  4 | >
  5 |    var x = document.getElementById("player");
    |        ^
  6 | 
  7 | 
  8 |     componentDidMount(){
```

This is the original JavaScript code.

```
<script>
    var x = document.getElementById("myAudio"); 

    function playAudio() { 
        x.play(); 
    } 

    function pauseAudio() { 
        x.pause(); 
    } 
</script>
```

My ReactJS code

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

export default class MediaPlayer extends Component{
    componentDidMount(){
        var x = document.getElementById("player"); 
    }

    onClickPlay() {
        x.play(); 
    }

    pauseAudio(){
        x.pause();
    }
    render(){
        return (
            <div>
            <h3>mediaplayer</h3>

            <audio id="player">
                <source src="https://samcloud.spacial.com/api/listen?sid=106487&m=sc&rid=184639" type="audio/mpeg"/></audio>
            <button onClick={this.onClickPlay}>Play</button>
            </div>
        )
    };
}
```

Comment: The code in the error message doesn't look like the code in the `MediaPlayer` class.

Comment: Hi Russel, just updated my answer with the alternative for React before v16.8. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem**: you are using `x` inside `onClickPlay` and `pauseAudio` functions, but they have a problem with this reference because the var is defined inside the `componentDidMount` scope.

**Solution**: look at this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-shirley-pf86k):

- Unify the play/pause logic in one single function `onClickPlay`.
- Note that `var x = document.getElementById("player");` is inside `onClickPlay`.
- I also used a hook to save a bool that indicates if `isPlaying` or not.

Hope it helps.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

const MediaPlayer = () => {
    const [isPlaying, setIsPlaying] = useState(false);

    const onClickPlay = () => {
        var x = document.getElementById("player");
        if (isPlaying) x.pause();
        else x.play();
        setIsPlaying(!isPlaying);
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <h3>media player</h3>
            <audio id="player">
                <source
                    src="https://samcloud.spacial.com/api/listen?sid=106487&m=sc&rid=184639"
                    type="audio/mpeg"
                />
            </audio>
            <button onClick={onClickPlay}>Play</button>
        </div>
    );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<MediaPlayer />, rootElement);
```

**Here you have the alternative for React before v16.8:**

```
class MediaPlayer extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { isPlaying: false }
        this.onClickPlay = this.onClickPlay.bind(this);
    }

    onClickPlay() {
        const { isPlaying } = this.state;
        var x = document.getElementById("player");
        if (isPlaying) x.pause();
        else x.play();
        this.setState({
            isPlaying: !isPlaying
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h3>media player</h3>
                <audio id="player">
                    <source src="https://samcloud.spacial.com/api/listen?sid=106487&m=sc&rid=184639" type="audio/mpeg" />
                </audio>
                <button onClick={this.onClickPlay}>Play</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<MediaPlayer />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

Comment: Hi Nico, my script did not like the above code as it wanted it formatted like the one below, I was unable to get yours to work.

it seems not to like const [isPlaying, setIsPlaying] = useState(false);

Comment: Hi Russell,  that's why you're using a version of reactJS prior to 16.8.   I will update my answer with the alternative to the older version.   I also recommend you to install the new reactJS version.

Answer (score 1):

Do this and it will work.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

export default class MediaPlayer extends Component{
    onClickPlay = () => {
        var x = document.getElementById("player");
        x.play();
    };

    pauseAudio(){
        var x = document.getElementById("player");
        x.pause();
    }
    render(){
        return (
            <div>
                <h3>media player</h3>

                <audio id="player">
                    <source src="https://samcloud.spacial.com/api/listen?sid=106487&m=sc&rid=184639" type="audio/mpeg"/></audio>
                <button onClick={this.onClickPlay}>Play</button>
            </div>
        )
    };
}
```

You are defining the variable 'x' in componentDidMount but the functions onClickPlay and pauseAudio does not understand what 'x' is as it is out of scope of those functions.